# I am unable to open the terminal

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu on VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host. The terminal doesn't open. I clicked on it, tried the shortcut, and opened from a file. Nothing works. The little loading circle spins for ~10 seconds and then the terminal tab disappears.

I've tried it on Ubuntu 22.04.1, and now 22.10. However, both behaved the same.

How can I open the terminal?

Comment: Please be clear and precise with details, you mention two release of Ubuntu, but I'm unsure which you're asking about. Default python versions differ between different releases of Ubuntu, and if you change the default python3 version, having a `gnome-terminal` fail to open would be expected, as many Ubuntu tools rely on python3 & the version the system comes with.

Comment: Right now, I have the 22.10 version installed, so I would prefer the solution for that one, but if you have a solution for any other version I would gladly download that one. I didn't update Python, the 3.10.7 version that I have now is the default.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 has python3.10.6 [as of today](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/python3). Since you have python3.10.7, you must have manually updated python at some point, which caused the issue. You can login to a virtual terminal `ctrl + alt + f3` to run commands. If that does not work, you will have to reinstall.

Comment: If you've changed the default python, you cannot use any commands that rely on python which are a large number of desktop features.  Using the base system (text terminal & no user-front-end tools, just basic GNU/Linux commands) will still work; ie. `wget` & `dpkg` can download where `apt` or front-end tools may have issues if you've changed python3 defaults.

Comment: FYI: Your question is still *unclear* mentioning both versions as per my first comment; if you wish answers/help, please amend your question.  This is a Q&A site, and comments are from us to the OP/original poster; replies/changes/details belong in the question, and once comments are addressed; they'll get deleted as it's the question itself that really matters.

Comment: I've tried everything recommended here and elsewhere several times, following official tutorials step by step, while reinstalling the entire system from time to time, yet nothing worked. I don't know what the problem is, and at this point, I'm starting to believe there is a demon inside my computer. I will use Xterm and try to get as much value out of it as I can before the demon comes out of my screen and brings eternal damnation to our plain. I'm truly sorry for summoning it, but I believe I can't be held responsible for this as I did it completely by accident and with no malicious intent.

Comment: Also, I guess I must be living in the future, because every time I reinstalled the system, 3.10.7 was the default version of Python that I got. Perhaps it's a time zone thing...